# unknown librasolv.so.2 needed by curl

Tags: curl

This error occurs when I execute curl:

```
curl: error while loading shared libraries: librasolv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've searched for this library but it's absent in my system (Raspberry Pi).

```
Linux ... 4.14.72-v7+ #1146 SMP Wed Sep 26 16:58:28 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

( I already executed "ldconfig" and the system is dist updated )

```
pi@sys ~ $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not  upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/197 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 110863 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.38.0-4+deb8u13_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.38.0-4+deb8u13) over (7.38.0-4+deb8u13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Setting up curl (7.38.0-4+deb8u13) ...
pi@sys ~ $ curl
curl: error while loading shared libraries: librasolv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found the library here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/libc6-armel-cross/filelist but I failed to install it

Comment: Please show the output of `ldd /path/to/curl`.

Comment: $ ldd /usr/bin/curl
    /usr/bin/curl: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblber-2.4.so.2: unsupported version 66 of Verdef record

Comment: sudo ldd /usr/bin/curl
/usr/bin/curl: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblber-2.4.so.2: ELF file data encoding not little-endian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# apt-get install --reinstall libldap-2.4-2
```